# What does the arrow mean in a function's argument in Swift 3.x?

Tags: swift, function, syntax, arguments

```
some_function(y_array: [Double], f_array: [(([Double], Double) -> Double)]) -> [Double] {

//some code

return some_array

}
```

I'm new to Swift and don't understand this notation. What does the ***first*** arrow mean in this context? This is an argument to a function.

Answer (score 0):

It means f_array is an array of clousers.
Closures are typically enclosed in curly braces { } and are defined by a function type () -> (), where -> separates the arguments and the return type.

```
([Double], Double) -> Double )
```

It means `clouser` takes two arguments one is array of double and another is double and returns a double element.

Eg:

```
let average = {(val1: [Double], val2: Double) -> Double in

   let sumOfAllValues =  val1.reduce(0, {$0 + $1})

    return sumOfAllValues / val2
}
```

Comment: Added more of the code so that you can see the full context better. Does your answer still apply?